# Emscripten generated HTML file does not work when opened, wasm binary must be preloaded

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I am able to correctly compile my `helloWorld.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

using the command: `emcc helloWorld.c -s WASM=1 -o helloWorld.html`

However when I open the file `helloWorld.html`, the follow error appears on the page:

> on the web, we need the wasm binary to be preloaded and set on
>   Module['wasmBinary']. emcc.py will do that for you when generating
>   HTML (but not JS) abort("on the web, we need the wasm binary to be
>   preloaded and set on Module['wasmBinary']. emcc.py will do that for
>   you when generating HTML (but not JS)") at Error
>       at jsStackTrace (file:///C:/workspaces/wasm/HelloWorld/helloWorld.js:1001:13)
>       at stackTrace (file:///C:/workspaces/wasm/HelloWorld/helloWorld.js:1018:12)
>       at abort (file:///C:/workspaces/wasm/HelloWorld/helloWorld.js:2414:44)
>       at getBinary (file:///C:/workspaces/wasm/HelloWorld/helloWorld.js:1528:7)
>       at file:///C:/workspaces/wasm/HelloWorld/helloWorld.js:1542:16

How can I get my app to load properly? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated `hmtl` file is meant to be served from a web server. If you check the browsers console you will likely see an error similar to this:

> Fetch API cannot load file:///{Your wasm file path}. URL scheme must
>   be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

To run your app using a local web server use the Emscripten command `emrun`:

```
emrun helloWorld.html
```

---

You may also see this error in a production environment, in which case it is likely that the request for the `.wasm` file has returned a non-200 status code.